# OpenVPN how to add route to AWS Load balancer

Tags: routing, openvpn, aws-elb

I have a load balancer in AWS, I want to restrict access in its security group to be accesible only from my OpenVPN server.

Now, I would like to use

```
push "route a.b.c.d 255.255.255.255"
```

in server.conf, in order to advertise the loadbalancer address to VPN clients as being accessible through the VPN

The problem here is that AWS uses CNAMEs for pointing to load balancers kind of `MyDomainELB-918273645.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com` instead of IPs

How could I advertise my clients to reach AWS load balancers through VPN ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution using an AWS internal load balancer instead of an AWS "internet-facing" load balancer. Then a CNAME pointing to load balancer will resolve an internal IP, the subnet of this IP must be pushed as a route in OpenVPN config file.